# How to design Restful uri for ManyToMany Relation

Tags: rest, jersey, entity-relationship, restful-url, restful-architecture

I am having confusion while choosing a database relation and Restful URI for application I am developing.

I am making a simple library application with following requirements.

1. Book can belong to many categories e.g Physics book belong to Textbook and Science Category. We can say book have many categories/labels/tags.
2. Viewing books in one category.
3. Viewing a book's all categories.
4. Searching book using categories or book information.
5. Book CRUD operations
6. Label CRUD operations

Considering all these requirements I choose **ManyToMany** relation between Books and Labels. I have implemented it using Hibernate Framework. 
Now when it came to designing Restful Services for this its getting very confusing.It makes me question table relationship choice as well.

Restful uri made yet.

/books

/books/{bookid}

/labels

/labels/{labelid}

But when I want to get a list of labels against a book, or a list of books against a label. How to map them using Restful URI. I can think of this

/book/{bookid}/labels

But considering this,how to map getting a list of books against one label

I want to know whether my choice of table relationship is right and if yes, how to design restful uri against it. And if no, please correct me and put a light on this scenario. Thanks

Comment: Refer this main blog http://www.restapitutorial.com/ and for specific resource naming http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URLs seem sound - so why not simply use:

```
/labels/{labelid}/books
```

for the 'books with a label' requirement?

Comment: But how to get Book's labels ( A list of labels against a book)
If we consider this url. then there are two url against the same resource. 
Jersey doesnt allow this.
`/books/{bookId}/labels`

Comment: The URL in the answer returns a list of books associated with a certain label, while /books/{bookid}/labels returns the labels associated with a certain book. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Rest URIs are "Resource" based, and you should probably look into how and when to use "Sub-Resources".
The table relationship choice is perfectly alright, and if you want any other complicated URIs, then you can also use REGEX in your URIs. You can follow this link to look at REGEX based URI matching.
http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/12/jax-rs-path-regex-based-uri-matching/

**For your case:**

==> to get list of all books with a labelId

```
   ../labels/{labelid}/books
```

==> to check if a particular book is associated with a particular label.

```
   ../labels/{labelid}/books/{bookid}
```

==> to get a list of all labels associated with a book.

```
   ../books/{bookid}/labels
```

==> to check if a particular label is associated with a particular book

```
   ../books/{bookid}/labels/{labelid}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different tack and support these URLs:

```
// get all books
GET /books

// get all books labeled "Sci-fi" and "Romance"
GET /books?label=Sci-fi&label=Romance

// get a specific book
GET /books/1234

// get all labels
GET /labels

// get all labels for book 1234
GET /labels?bookId=1234

// get a specific label
GET /labels/Sci-fi
```

Another option is to create a mapping resource:

```
// get links to all labels for book 1234
GET /book-labels?bookId=1234

// get links to all books labeled Sci-fi
GET /book-labels?label=Sci-fi
```